# Tomcat: Class not found in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: classloader, tomcat7

I am using a non open source library for working with images. This library relies on JAI (jai_imageio.jar) for JPEG2000 image type. In a stand-alone program things work just fine and JPEG2000 images are processed correctly. However, when these two JARs are deployed to Tomcat within a WAR the required JAI class(es) are not found. Furthermore, if I place jai_imageio.jar in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` the JAI class is found and things work correctly.

The vendor tells me they locate the required class as follows:

```
Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("JPEG2000");
```

My theory here is that because ImageIO is part of the JRE the classloader being used is the "Common" classloader rather than the one for the WAR. For this reason the JAR within the WAR is not found but the one in the Tomcat lib directory is. Does this sound right or is something else going on?

I would prefer not to deploy the JAI JAR to the Tomcat lib directory; I want to release it as part of the WAR. Is there a way around this class loading issue? As I mentioned, I don't have access to the source. I may be able to ask for some change to facilitate WAR deployment but I'm not sure what that might be, perhaps a method to set the reader but this seems kludgy.

I appreciate feedback on any part of this. Thanks.

Comment: I found calling ImageIO.scanForPlugins() solves my problem. Sorry for the bother.